# Fix Workspaces in XFCE with Multiple Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce, workspaces

I recently install XFCE, and got dual monitors working by installing the AMD Catalyst drivers. Now I have one workspace per monitor. When dragging windows from one monitor to another, they are instead dragged to a different workspace on the same monitor.

I am wondering how to fix this.

Comment: How did you get one workspace per monitor? As far as I know that's not possible in Xfce (this has been discussed in [this thread](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9319)).

Answer (score 3):

Xfce `4.10` has only limited support for multiple monitors. The upcoming `4.12` is better at that. You can try installing the (unreleased) 4.12 from [ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12)?

Additionally, you can set up the monitors properly by using `arandr`.

Comment: I think you meant `xrandr` not *arandr*

Comment: No, he means arandr.